# How does Bitbake know to source conf/bitbake.conf

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am having an issue where a recipe i'm using no longer has the variable `libdir` defined. It appears to only have `libdir_native`.

This recipe i'm using is [poco-1.7.5](https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded/tree/morty/meta-oe/recipes-support/poco) for `Morty` from `openembedded` so I assume the recipe should work properly.

As a result of the missing `libdir` variable none of the installed files are being packaged which is screwing up my build.

In the short term i've been able to fix the problem by creating an `append` file which makes `libdir = "${libdir_native}` but this doesn't seem like it should be necessary.

The only thing I can think of is that the `Bitbake.conf` file is not being source properly by `Bitbake` (or the wrong `.conf` is being used).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Recipe seems fine. Can you show how you came to the conclusion that libdir is not set when do_package happens?  `bitbake -e poco|grep ^FILES_` will show you what it tries to package.

Comment: Interesting! I had run `bitbake -e poco|grep ^libdir` which gave me:

`libdir_nativesdk="/usr/lib"`, `libdir_native="/usr/lib"`
```
Which I assumed was telling me that `libdir` simply did not exist.

Ran the command you pasted and got all the packages listed (Thank you!) and they are all trying to be installed in `/usr/lib64`.

However, when running the Poco recipe I get: `WARNING: poco-1.7.5-r0 do_package: QA Issue: poco: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:` and the files listen are prepended with `/usr/lib`.
So `libdir` is set to `/usr/lib64`?

Comment: Any suggestions on how I can force the packages to install to `/usr/lib`? Right now, I have a `bbappend` for Poco which sets `libdir = `/usr/lib` but I'm interested in finding a more permanent solution.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments this seems to be the problem: Poco upstream installs libraries into /usr/lib/ but the yocto packaging expects them to be in ${libdir} which may be different from /usr/lib/.

The most common reason (for cmake recipes) for this is that the upstream project does not support CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR. Check if the upstream build system has some alternative means for specifying libdir -- this is surprisingly common with cmake projects. If not, you could add support for CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR in the upstream build system (and add a patch to your recipe).

An alternative hack would be to add a `do_install_append()` that checks if ${libdir} is not /usr/lib/, and moves everything from ${D}/usr/lib/ to ${D}${libdir} in that case.

Comment: The problem i'm having is tracking down where ${libdir} is being set to `/usr/lib64`. Any suggestions on how I might find this?

Comment: I wonder why you need to?  ${libdir} is allowed to have a value that is not not "/usr/lib", the recipe should be able to live with that... If I remember correctly the most common reason for it being "/usr/lib64" is that your OS supports multilib (e.g. 32 bit applications on 64 bit system). In that case, see baselib variable in meta/conf/multilib.conf.

Comment: It is the `poco` recipe which is forcing me to worry about having `${libdir}` set to `/usr/lib`. It literally does not package the libraries if if `${libdir}` is anything but `/usr/lib`.

I am also curious why this is. Mostly, I just want to solve this problem so I don't have to hack on modifications to recipes.

Comment: The recipe should package files correctly _if_ they get installed in ${libdir} as they should be: check $WORKDIR/image/ directory to see where they ended up (or read $WORKDIR/temp7log.do_install). My answer lists a couple of ways to fix the situation if it the libraries are indeed installed in /usr/lib/ when they should not be.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Any tips on disabling multilib?

This issue has become a source of other problems. For example, the Python3 libraries are installed in /usr/lib64 as well and causes a crash when I try to run it.

I have been able to fix this problem in the short term by symlinking everything from /usr/lib64 to /usr/lib but i'd like to just turn off muiltilib support if it is possible.